# How to continue the string when hitting enter in vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code, pycharm

I am currently using PyCharm where my strings keep being string when I hit enter inside it. It looks like this:

```py
string = "Hello"
         "keeps being here"
```

while in VS Code it looks like this:

```py
string = "Hello
its not here"
```

Unfortunately, I don't know what this is called, so if someone could share their knowledge, this would be great.